# create bochs project in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, bochs

I'm trying to use the cpu of bochs in my graduate course project. I want to create a project of it in eclipse so I can modify it and compile it and also see the errors ...

I have the source code and I use visual studio's nmake to build, compile it. but the problem is that it doesn't report me the errors and the only way to know the error happens or not is to wait until nmake ends and see if the .exe file is created or not. after that the process of finding errors is a bad headache.

so I'm trying to use ubuntu OS and use eclipse. anyone knows how to create a project for bochs in this?

Also the more important thing is a tutorial that I can learn bochs cpu codes. because the official site's tutorial has no use.

Answer (score 0):

haha,
I found it myself.
just go to bochs official site and download the source code for linux.
extract the zip file somewhere.
open a terminal and go to the extracted folder.
type:

```
./configure
```

this will check your system and set the values for the #define arguments in a file called makefile.

now open eclipse.(I assume that you have the c/c++ CDT). FILE>NEW PROJECT

In the opened dialogue open c/c++ tree, and select "Makefile project with existing code" and click next. next put a name for your project and in the "existing code location" browse the extracted folder. next select CROSS GCC as toolchain. then click finish.

there you go. now build the project and it should work.

remember that for running project you must give bochs command line arguments which is available in eclipse and you can find out how with a search in forums.